# Maven -T thread count, Surefire 3.x parallelism, and Bamboo 5.x unit test total

Tags: maven, bamboo, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm building a multimodule Java project with Maven on Bamboo 5.x, the Surefire test output for some modules seem to be interleaved after upgrading from Surefire 2.15 to Surefire 3.0.0-M5. Moreover Bamboo seems to think there are far fewer tests being run in total, although the build log is about the same length. I don't see any configuration for parallel tests, although Maven is using `-T 3` in both configurations to build the entire project with multiple threads (that is, the Bamboo job uses `-T 3` when it invokes `mvn`).

Why would upgrading Surefire 2.15 to Surefire 3.0.0-M5 suddenly cause the groups of tests in the output to be interleaved? And would this affect the number of tests Bamboo 5.x thinks has been run?

Comment: First really using a seven year old plugin (2.15)? ... Second the question is what you mean by: ` Maven is using -T 3 ..` .. So someone has configured it that way... There could be issued related to parallelization in tests... maybe if tests are not really separated as they should be. See more details about  https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html Apart from that I would recheck running without multiple threads  in comparison to running with threads...

Comment: Do you use *forkCount=1* or *forkMode=once*? If yout CI server Bamboo uses *-T 3* and your tests run in-process then the system properties may interleave but not the groups. As a JUnit4 example, follow the groups configuration hints https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories

Comment: At one point I thought that Surefire was turning on parallel execution because of the Maven `-T` command line option, but that turned out not to be the case after all. In the end I don't know why the output was interleaved and the total number of tests displayed in Bamboo was incorrect. Since I am no longer on that project, I won't be able to investigate further.